# No channel 13 after ddwrt firmware

Tags: dd-wrt

I flashed my TP-Link 1043ND to dd-wrt, and the channels 12 and 13 disappeared from the settings. I am in Europe so they are legal. The dd-wrt version is v24SP2 build 21061.

How do I get them back?

Comment: What version of dd-wrt did you get. Mine even has channel 14 and i'm in Europe ;-)

Comment: Is this WR1043N(D)? What's your HW revision?

Comment: Minimum [requirement](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#TP-Link) is "WR1043ND v.24 SP2 - build 13972 - 20100223". What's your build number? You can try a different build number.

Comment: Completed the opening post.